# Java HttpServlet unable to receive any parameters from POST request made by client using OKHttp

Tags: java, servlets, okhttp

This is the log from the server:

```
POST Request reader reads:--3cd58f21-8ffa-46a0-b1c0-0e4660c2ca28
POST Request reader reads:Content-Disposition: form-data; name="device"
POST Request reader reads:Content-Length: 163
POST Request reader reads:
POST Request reader reads:{"deviceId":"5ccf7f0fb7b1","manufacturer":"Wow Lamp","name":"Wow-b7b1","type":"lamp","userId":"amzn1.account.AGGL3JOPQ3UTF74KQY2TJCYSYNAQ","timer":0,"chosen":true}
POST Request reader reads:--3cd58f21-8ffa-46a0-b1c0-0e4660c2ca28--
```

The result above is what the reader read from the request. But if getParameter is called from the request instance, the parameter map is null.

This is the content of the parameter map:

```
POST Request:{}
```

As you can see, the map contains no parameter, but the reader can read the data sent by the client.

This is the code of the server:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException
{       
    System.out.println("POST Request:" + req.getParameterMap());

    if(isPostRequestValid(req))
    {
        try 
        {
            handleRequest(req);
        } 

        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    sendResponse(resp);

    try 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = req.getReader();

        String inputLine;

        while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println("POST Request reader reads:" + inputLine);
        }
    } 

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

There must be some coding mistake in the client side

This is the code of the client:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
                        .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM) //this is what I say in my POSTman (Chrome plugin)
                        .addFormDataPart("device", device)
                        .build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url(Constant.BASE_URL + "update_device.html")
                        .post(requestBody)
                        .build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String responseString = response.body().string();
                    response.body().close();
                    // do whatever you need to do with responseString
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

But the client side did use form data, so what can be wrong here?

Comment: What is the version of the OkHttp  are you using?

Comment: @Serhiy the version is 2.5.1

Comment: Hmm, I cannot find that version in Maven central.. there is 2.5.0 and 2.6.0.. but not 2.5.1.. I also cannot find javadoc for 2.5.1.. Double check the version please..

Comment: @Serhiy sorry, the version is 2.5.0

Comment: What servlet version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve the problem by updating my OKHttpClient to version 3.6 and then change the request body part of my code to this

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("key", "value")
        .build();
```

It seems that my version of OKHttpClient before does not include the functionality to send parameters of content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Before updating, OKHttpClient can only send parameter of content type `multipart/form-data`. But for the servlet side, I was unable to parse this content type. I tried using the method `getPart("key")` however an exception was thrown after accessing that method.

So, updating OKHttpClient to version 3.6 will allow me to use the `FormBody` class which sends request parameters with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type. This way, the servlet side can now get the parameters via `request.getParameter("key")` method.

Comment: That is why I was asking what version of servlets you are using, because version 2 does not support `multipart/form-data` (while version 3 already does). Glad you managed to get this sorted.

Comment: @Serhiy Yes, while you were asking for the version number. I was in the process of solving the problem after updating OKHttpClient. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP POST parameters are received in a Servlet via request parameters, not by reading the request body.

Comment: I can only get the parameters if the content-type set by the client is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. If it's multipart/form-data, then reading parameter will always be null.